# Why does norm.pdf of evenly spaced values give a normal distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, normal-distribution

Can anyone please explain what goes behind the scenes of a norm.pdf function in python?
I saw a uniform distribution (formed using `x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.001)`) being used to plot a normal distribution using `plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x))`. So how does norm.pdf convert uniformly distributed values into a normal distribution?

Comment: What do you not understand from the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

`pdf` is short for 'Probability Density Function', it represents the density of a random distribution for a given value; that is, how likely is that distribution to output that value? This is the most commonly plotted chart for most distributions, since peaks (on the y axis) represent commonly output values (on the x axis).

Statistical distributions, like the normal/gaussian distribution, have a nice, often parametrized, function to performs this mapping. `norm.pdf` refers to the PDF for a normal distribution, [which you can find here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution).

Hence, `plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x))` plots, for a bunch of x values, how likely the normally-distributed random variable `norm` is to output a value of `x`, hence the bell curve that gets plotted.